# Any way to automate Flash/SilverLight file upload testing?

Tags: flash

It could have been easier if Flash/SilverLight made it possible to trigger file dialog programmatically, but file should still be selected, dialog confirmed, upload initiated... Looks like it has to be automated from outside. What's the usual automation path in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash and Silverlight are generally difficult to automate because they don't have full MSAA/UIAutomation implementations.  Silverlight has been getting better, but specifically to your question, the file upload dialog is not actually a part of Flash or Silverlight and is MSAA/UIAutomation compliant.

You can use UIAutomation (the new replacement of MSAA) directly, or use any win32 automation framework to interact with that dialog.

Comment: Can you supply a reference to any good win32 automation framework?

Comment: If you are only going to need it for a couple of dialogs then an entire win32 automation framework might be overkill and you should consider just using UIAutomation, however if you plan on using a win32 UI automation framework to test your silverlight or flash based application then you should find a good framework to use.  I know you can use PowerShell: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163301.aspx, and there are a lot of others out there.  Unfortunately, my experience with win32 UI automation frameworks was internal to Microsoft.  I don't have experience with any publicly available.

Comment: If you're still looking, AutoIT might be an option: http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/ I've used it in conjunction with WebDriver to automate manipulating a file dialog that's actually generated by a flash utility embedded in a website I'm testing.

Answer (score 1):

Telerik provides their own Silverlight Test Automation Tool. They predominantly work on .NET platform. You can check

- Microsoft Silverlight Test Automation ( http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/products/silverlight-testing.aspx)
- Telerik product products / addresses features not supported in VSTS Test version. They were the first to offer silverlight support even before VSTS provided support for silverlight. More details on feature comparision please check http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/products/test-studio-vs-visual-studio-2010-comparison.aspx
- Third option is 'Free Testing Framework' provided by Telerik ( http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/free-testing-framework.aspx) . Please check if this helps. Please share your learning's / feedback if you try evaluating telerik products